# Loading chuck X failed at production after deploy

Tags: angular, angular6

[image]I am using angular 6.0.7, my app contains almost 10 modules, after deploying to production at AWS, sometimes I get loading chuck X failed.

I have tried lamda functions to load children module in route file, that seems to work on local and module rendering speed became faster, but I was not able to build for production it was saying

Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'AppRoutes'.

Comment: can you share the complete error from the console

Comment: @AkberIqbal I have updated my question